# Getting 404 not found error for POST ajax request Laravel 5.2

Tags: php, ajax, post, laravel-5, http-status-code-404

I am upgrading my `laravel 4` app to `laravel 5.2` and there are so many things which I have to reconsider in my codes. One of this is the `CSRF` thing for `AJAX` requests. I can't figure out how to handle it properly in my routes file.
Of course, I have include the meta for csrf in my view:

```
<meta name="csrf-token" content="{{ csrf_token() }}" />
```

my routes file:

```
Route::post('/edituser', 'UsersController@toEditUser');
```

my script:

```
var _token = $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content');

function triggerEditUser(id){
    $.post(_token+'/edituser',{id:id},function(data){
        if(data){
            console.log(data);
        }
    });
}
```

my controller:

```
public function toEditUser(){
        if(Request::ajax()){
            $user = User::find(Input::get('id'));
            return Response::json($user);
        }
    }
```

I'm getting the error message:

```
http://mysite.local/kg9VLUc0QWP59AqSP0OCPWjwsWPg33ypZ47FecRC/edituser 404 (Not Found)
```

Comment: Are you sure ```kg9VLUc0QWP59AqSP0OCPWjwsWPg33ypZ47FecRC``` in your url path ??

Comment: I think you should pass the csrf token in header or as data

Answer (score 0):

May be your solution would be something like

```
$.post( '/edituser',{id:id, token:_token},function(data){
```

in place of

```
$.post(_token+'/edituser',{id:id},function(data){
```

Answer (score 0):

As given Laravel [documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/routing#csrf-protection), you should use the headers to send the **csrf** token.

```
$.ajaxSetup({
        headers: {
            'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
        }
});
```

,

```
$.post('/edituser',{id:id,_token:_token},function(data){
        if(data){
            console.log(data);
        }
    });
```

Alternatively, you can also send the token as the data

Comment: I still receive POST http://mysite.local/edituser 500 (Internal Server Error) with this code

Comment: ok. can you check the xhr in developer tools, to check what response you getting ?

Answer (score 0):

just to test and tell me the answer.
 in your controller change

```
public function toEditUser(){
        if(Request::ajax()){
            $user = User::find(Input::get('id'));
            return Response::json($user);
        }
    }
```

by

```
public function toEditUser(){
        if(Request::ajax()){
            $user = User::find(Input::get('id'));

        foreach ($user as $u) {
            $users[]=$result->yourcolumn;
        }

           return $users;
        }
    }
```

and add

```
 $.ajaxSetup({
            headers: {
              'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
            }
          });
```